# Is it safe to attach a 8.5Amps device to a fuse tap?

Tags: wiring, fuse, fuse-panel

Would it be safe to attach a device that pulls max 8.5A according to the manufacterer to a fuse tap? I'm scared that the wire will overload.

I have my eyes on a 10A fuse for interior lights to tap into. (edit: think I'll go for a 20A wind screen washer pump fuse as the use time of this is really short)